# How to obtain round hover on "round" div?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is any way to make div that acts like it was round.

I have tried:

```
img {
    width: 350px;
    border : 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 175px;
}

img:hover {
   border-color : blue;
}
```

but I get blue border when I enter square area (350x350)

Edit:
This code works in Firefox, not but in Chrome.

Comment: Works for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: How about this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2d9H5/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy I'm using Chrome. I've checked in Firefox and there it works perfectly

Comment: @alicjasalamon How about the demo I put in a comment. I dont know why firefox displays it like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLzwL/1/)

```
img {
width: 350px;
border : 2px solid red;
-webkit-border-radius: 175px;
-moz-border-radius: 175px;
border-radius: 175px;
height:350px;
}
img:hover {
border-color : blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is any way to make div what acts like it was round.

The answer is NO.

HTML elements are rectangular although they can be tweaked to **appear** other shapes.

There are, however, other tricks to achieve the effect you are after but it will depend on what you are **precisely** trying to do.

@Ruddy provided a fiddle in his comment which might be one answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are searching for

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Unfortunatly there is no way you can make a round element that is crossbrowser compatible.
There is (i think) only this way, with an image map.

```
<img src="http://freshwateraquaculture.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/300x300.gif" alt="" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
<map name="Map">
  <area shape="poly" coords="112,300,50,186,56,66,248,58,330,114,320,244,220,298" href="#">
</map>
```

If you inspect the Element with a Developer tool like Google Chrome Developer tool od 'Firebug' you can see that the area has a special form and is not rectal.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've used javascript to make it work in Chrome

```
$('#photo').mousemove(function (e) {
    var r = 175;

    var x = $('#photo').offset().left + r;
    var y = $('#photo').offset().top + r;

    var ex = e.pageX;
    var ey = e.pageY;

    var xx = (ex - x);
    var yy = (ey - y);

    if(xx*xx+yy*yy<r*r)
        $("#photo").css('border-color', 'red');
    else
        $("#photo").css('border-color', 'blue');
});

$('#photo').mouseleave(function (e) {
        $("#photo").css('border-color', 'blue');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A676k/)

#### CSS

```
img {
    width: 350px;
    border : 2px solid red;
     /* Safari 3 to 4, iOS 1 to 3.2, Android 1.6 */
    -webkit-border-radius: 175px;

     /* Firefox 1 to 3.6 */
    -moz-border-radius: 175px;

    /* Opera 10, IE 9, Safari 5+, Chrome, Firefox 4+, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
    border-radius: 175px;
}

img:hover {
   border-color : blue;
}
```